# Typeahead.js JSON, PDO issue

Tags: php, json, pdo, bootstrap-typeahead

Using typeahead, cannot seem to fetch results using PDO. Have looked the best I can with my limited English, could not find a solution, maybe I am doing something wrong in the PHP? here is the breakdown:

Using typehead.js and bootstrap 3.

HTML :

```
<input type="text" class="seek typeahead" id="seekInput" placeholder="Search" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.seek.typeahead').typeahead({                               
          name: "seek",                
        remote: 'include/search.php?store=%QUERY'
    });
});
```

Search.php and where I am trying to generate the array for typeahead:

```
require_once ('konnekt.php');

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT store FROM retailers WHERE  store or country LIKE :country");
$country = (isset($_POST['query']) === true) ? $_POST['query'] : '';
$query->bindValue(':country', '%' . $country . '%' );
$query->execute();
foreach ($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

Here is my what my browser is saying:

STATUS 200

Response: `[{"store":"Aplace"},{"store":"Aplace"},{"store":"Design Only"}]`

Whats happening live:

[image: Undefined]

Comment: Did you replace %QUERY by the value in the input field?

Comment: You can rewrite `'%' . $country . '%'` as `"%{$country}%"`.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, typeahead.js will render `<p/>` tags using the default datum format, which can be as simple as an array of strings:

```
[
    "Aplace",
    "Aplace",
    "Design Only"
]
```

These strings will be automatically converted into [datums](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/#datum), which is the typeahead name for the format that defines both how data is both displayed and how the query is matched against the data.

Here's how you would output that array of strings in PHP, using your original example:

```
require_once ('konnekt.php');
$result = array();
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT store FROM retailers WHERE  store or country LIKE :country");
$country = (isset($_POST['query']) === true) ? $_POST['query'] : '';
$query->bindValue(':country', '%' . $country . '%' );
$query->execute();
foreach ($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
    $result[] = $row["store"];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

If you'd prefer to continue to use `store` as the key for your data, you can:

- Set the `valueKey` parameter in the original typeahead definition:

  ```
  $('.seek.typeahead').typeahead({                               
      name: "seek",                
      remote: 'include/search.php?store=%QUERY',
      valueKey: 'store'
  });
  ```

And then also return the required `tokens` property for each datum:

```
    [
      {
        "store": "Aplace",
        "tokens": ["Aplace"]
      },
      {
        "store": "Aplace",
        "tokens": ["Aplace"]
      },
      {
        "store": "Design Only",
        "tokens": ["Design", "Only"]
      }
    ]
```

Note that the tokens are arrays of single words, which are the actual values used by typeahead to match your query against.

Comment: thanks for your response! it helped me understand better. How best can achieve this calling data from mysql using PHP? I am still having trouble.

Comment: I just added PHP that *should* work for your example, caveat the actual data

Comment: this example does work, the issue is now it does not drop the results that have to reference, it just lists array, the auto-complete results are not narrowed down as I type..

Comment: In your original example, there were two identical rows from the database.  Ideally, the like statement would be setup so that as the query has more characters, less results are returned from the db.  Is it possible that matching against `store` and `country` is too inclusive?

Comment: I tried eliminating this and just simply going for store. It generates but does not narrows down when im typing, it just lists the array.

Comment: Does the JSON returned from PHP change when you add additional characters to the `query` `$_POST` variable?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40150/discussion-between-sethcodes-and-jeff-sisson)